# Adding key in spread operator inside a loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a state like:

```
this.state = {
  questionListData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      question: "Who was the first man to step on Moon?",
      options: [
        {
          opt: "Abdul Kalam"
        },
        {
          opt: "Albert Einstein"
        },
        {
          opt: "Sheldon Cooper"
        },
        {
          opt: "Salman Khan"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: "Who was the Second man to step on Moon?",
      options: [
        {
          opt: "Abdul Kalam2"
        },
        {
          opt: "Albert Einstein2"
        },
        {
          opt: "Sheldon Cooper2"
        },
        {
          opt: "Salman Khan2"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      question: "Who was the Third man to step on Moon?",
      options: [
        {
          opt: "Abdul Kalam3"
        },
        {
          opt: "Albert Einstein3"
        },
        {
          opt: "Sheldon Cooper3"
        },
        {
          opt: "Salman Khan3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      question: "Who was the Fourth man to step on Moon?",
      options: [
        {
          opt: "Abdul Kalam"
        },
        {
          opt: "Albert Einstein"
        },
        {
          opt: "Sheldon Cooper"
        },
        {
          opt: "Salman Khan"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

I am dynamically adding to this list of questions under the `questionListData` array. While adding, id is not generated as it is user defined. So i want to automatically add an id if it is not there. for that i had done this:

```
this.state.questionListData.map((r,u)=>{

        console.log('new r',r)

        if(!this.state.questionListData[u].id){alert('!r.id')
       this.setState({...this.state.questionListData[u], id:u+1 })
        }
    })
```

But if I do this, `id` is not added in that perticular index of the `questionListData` array, but outside it, like so:

```
questionListData:[
    "id":4
    {"id":1,
         "question":"Who was the first man to step on Moon?",
         "options":[
            {"opt":"Abdul Kalam"},
        {"opt":"Albert Einstein"},
        {"opt":"Sheldon Cooper"},
        {"opt":"Salman Khan"}
          ]

        }

]
```

Please help me with the correct syntax of spread operator to add the `id` to that pwrticular index inside `this.setState`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes because you're adding id in your state and not in your list object in your state.

```
const newList = this.state.questionListData.map((obj, idx) => {
  if(!obj.id){
    obj.id = idx + 1;
  }
  return obj;
});
this.setState({ questionListData: newList });
```

Comment: Its is bad practice to change state directly and it can cause bugs later on. You need to use setState when you want to change state.

Comment: You can "clone" your list by using spreading ```[...this.state.questionListData]``` for sure, but applying immediatly setState function there is not a problem.

Comment: @Andrea-codemillers.com you're not returning anything from map, so `newList` will be an array of `undefined` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const newList = this.state.questionListData.map((item, index) => {
  if (!item.id) {
    return {
      ...item,
      id: index + 1
    }
  }
  return item;
})

this.setState({questionListData: newList});
```